# chained List of nodes' parent pointers not behaving correctly c++

Tags: list, c++11, pointers, vector, nodes

I'm currently working on an A* algorithm implementation in c++, but i've been facing a problem that I really don't understand.
Let me show you my code :

```
// This is my object node
// In case the error might have been in here
// I implemented myself the copy constructor,
// because i thought it might have been my error, but it wasn't
struct node
{
   node()
   {
    this->x = 0;
    this->y = 0;
    this->g = 0;
    this->h = 0;
    this->f = 0;
    this->parent = nullptr;
   }

   node(const node &b)
   {
    this->x = b.x;
    this->y = b.y;
    this->g = b.g;
    this->h = b.h;
    this->f = b.f;
    this->parent = b.parent;
   }

   node *parent;
   int x, y;
   float g, h, f;

   node operator=(const node &b)
   {
    this->x = b.x;
    this->y = b.y;
    this->g = b.g;
    this->h = b.h;
    this->f = b.f;
    this->parent = b.parent;

    return *this;
   }
   bool operator==(const node b) const { return b.x == x && b.y == y; }
   bool operator!=(const node b) const { return !(b.x == x && b.y == y); }
};

// Here i find the lowest F score element
auto b = std::min_element (openNodes.begin(), openNodes.end(), compareFScore);

// I deference the previous iterator to get the object
auto curr = *b;

// If it is the solution i was looking for, then return the path
if (curr == end)
    return reconstructPath(curr);

// else i add the curr node to the closed nodes
// and remove it from open nodes
closedNodes.push_back(curr);
openNodes.remove(curr);

// Since that last iterator got removed, i simply get it back from closed nodes
auto c = closedNodes.rbegin();
node current;

// Here the error happens.
// a node's parent is simply a pointer to another node
// c contains all information valid, let's say its parent is 0x0002
// the parent of the parent of c being 0x0001
// the 3rd parent being nullptr (0x0000)
current.parent = c->parent;
```

on that last line, current.parent = c->parent, even if c contains all valid information and has a nice chained-list of nodes, the affectation current.parent = c->parent creates an infinite list of nodes pointing to itself. In other words :

```
current.parent = c->parent; // Just as described in the code above
// in debug mode, when i get here, current.parent points to 0x0002, which is correct
// BUT current.parent.parent points to 0x0002 too, while it should point to 0x0001
// and current.parent.parent.parent points to 0x0002 aswell, simply making it an infinite chained-list of doom.
// The worst of all is the node c also changed here to become exactly the same as current,
// while the line before it was 100% correct in debug mode.
```

It isn't my first time working with chained lists, but it sure is the first time this weird behavior happens.

thanks for your help!

Comment: I forgot to mention, openNodes and closedNodes are list<node>, not vector<node>.

Comment: It's a bit unclear because you haven't included some of the referenced code. But, my guess is that you're copying nodes (when you do things like `push_back`) when you don't mean to be, and then you continue to modify the original rather than the copy. Also, unrelated, if this is C++11, please don't use bare pointers for this, used `std::shared_ptr`.

Comment: Your copy constructor and assignment operators replicate the defaults (aside from getting the return value wrong on the assignment operator). You could simplify your entire class down to this: http://ideone.com/whwtaE

Comment: I know about the copy. I thought somehow my compiler went nuts, ignore these parts of the code it ain't what i'm looking for ^^.

Also i found the issue, read my answer, thanks :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my error,

Actually the lists and vectors messes around with normal pointers (for some reasons, if someone can explain i'd love to learn more !), so by using shared_ptr rather than strict pointers everywhere (including in my objects), it fixed the issue.